# Render a custom directive from a controller variable

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a controller which fetches a template from the database. In this template i have a custom directive, for example:

```
<custom-directive> </custom-directive>
```

I'm printing this template to my php document from the controller. The problem is that it won't render the custom directive after i print it from the controller.

i'm really hoping you guys could help me out here. Is there anyway to let the custom directive render after the template is printed to the html?

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm not an expert on using Angular with PHP, but I believe you'll need to have the component in your template from the beginning with Angular, and you can use something like an `*ngIf` to display or not display that component.

So if you have multiple options for which component you'd like to display, perhaps you can restructure your code to use an [ngSwitch](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/directives/ng_switch_directives.html), listing out the possible component options.

Comment: you may be able to use the compile functionality: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile
I don't really use php, but I've used this in javascript when adding components after the view has rendered

Comment: @JackKoppa I use a http request to fetch the data and i assign the response (the small template, in this case) to a variable. So i don't think this is an option. But many thanks for your willingness to help.

Comment: @XJ2 - sounds good, I actually believe I was mistaken anyway. If you're calling it `<custom-directive>`, that likely means you're using [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), correct? If so, ignore my comment, and we should remove the "angular" tag from the question (which my comment is in reference to)

Comment: @JackKoppa Ah yes, i am sorry, i must have accidentally added the Angular tag too.

Comment: @jgerstle i can't seem to figure it out, unfortunately.

Comment: you are going to need to do something like $compile(document.body.getElementsByTagName("custom-directive")[0]) in your angular controller once the tag is loaded in. I don't really understand why you can't use ng-if (angular 1s *ngIf) though.